# htaccess mod_rewrite: Force using https, but not on subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, subdomain

I want to force users to use https on my site. I use this piece of code in the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It all works fine, expect that it forces https on subdomains too (eg. subdomain.mysite.com is forced to https as well). I want to force only my domain to https, and not any of the subdomains.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what should work:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.){0,1}mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Please tell me if it did the trick ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer! It doesn't work completly. When you go to mysite.com without putting www. in front of it, it doesn't redirect to https. The subdomains doens't redirect anymore, and www.mysite.com does redirect! Thanks for that.

Comment: Ok I didn't know you wanted without the www. I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! It works fine now! Can you explain me how you did this?

Comment: Wow that's looooooooooong. You need to spend some time on what has become one of my favorite page: RewriteRules: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html . Anyway it's all about RegExp. My favorite tool to check for regexp: http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!).

Comment: And by the way: if you do **only** this: `^(.*)$` you can replace it by `(.*)` (like I did in my answer).